# dynamic programming and continuation passing style

Tags: algorithm, recursion, f#, dynamic-programming, continuations

for simple problems like fibonacci, writing CPS is *relatively* straightforward

```
let  fibonacciCPS n =
  let rec fibonacci_cont a cont =
    if a <= 2 then cont 1
    else
      fibonacci_cont (a - 2) (fun x ->
        fibonacci_cont (a - 1) (fun y ->
          cont(x + y)))

  fibonacci_cont n (fun x -> x)
```

However, in the case of the rod-cutting exemple from [here](http://faculty.ycp.edu/~dbabcock/PastCourses/cs360/lecture/lecture13.html)  (or the book [intro to algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)), the number of closure is not always equal to 2, and can't be hard coded.

I imagine one has to change the intermediate variables to sequences.

(I like to think of the continuation as a contract saying "when you have the value, pass it on to me, then i'll pass it on to my boss after treatment" or something along those line, which defers the actual execution)

For the rod cutting, we have

```
//rod cutting
let p = [|1;5;8;9;10;17;17;20;24;30|]

let rec r n = seq { yield p.[n-1]; for i in 1..(n-1) -> (p.[i-1] + r (n-i)) } |> Seq.max 
[1 .. 10] |> List.map (fun i -> i, r i)
```

In this case, I will need to attached the newly created continuation

```
let cont' = fun (results: _ array) -> cont(seq { yield p.[n-1]; for i in 1..(n-1) -> (p.[i-1] + ks.[n-i]) } |> Seq.max)
```

to the "cartesian product" continuation made by the returning subproblems.
Has anyone seen a CPS version of rod-cutting / has any tips on this ?

Comment: Wouldn't pattern matching be more straightforward?

Comment: in the end, I'll need to take the max of a sequence at each step, so I dont see how it reduces noise

Comment: i think I need to 'collect' the sub continuations with a 'compose' operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to explicitly CPS everything, which means some nice stuff like the list comprehension will be lost (maybe using async blocks can help, I don't know F# very well) -- so starting from a simple recursive function:

```
let rec cutrod (prices: int[]) = function
    | 0 -> 0
    | n -> [1 .. min n (prices.Length - 1)] |>
           List.map (fun i -> prices.[i] + cutrod prices (n - i)) |>
           List.max
```

It's clear that we need CPS versions of the list functions used (map, max and perhaps a list-building function if you want to CPS the [1..(blah)] expression too). map is quite interesting since it's a higher-order function, so its first parameter needs to be modified to take a CPS-ed function instead. Here's an implementation of a CPS List.map:

```
let rec map_k f list k = 
  match list with
    | [] -> k []
    | x :: xs -> f x (fun y -> map_k f xs (fun ys -> k (y :: ys)))
```

Note that map_k invokes its argument f like any other CPS function, and puts the recursion in map_k into the continuation. With map_k, max_k, gen_k (which builds a list from 1 to some value), the cut-rod function can be CPS-ed:

```
let rec cutrod_k (prices: int[]) n k = 
  match n with
    | 0 -> k 0
    | n -> gen_k (min n (prices.Length - 1)) (fun indices ->
               map_k (fun i k -> cutrod_k prices (n - i) (fun ret -> k (prices.[i] + ret))) 
                     indices 
                     (fun totals -> max_k totals k))
```

Comment: Very instructive way of approaching it

Comment: Extending your systematic approach, it makes sense that there is a one to one correspondence between forward style and CP style, hence a mechanical transformation between the two. Do you know any good paper/link that illustrate/explore this ?

Comment: In fsharp specifically, probably one could use a CPS expression builder to do the bookkeeping, as CPS seem to be generalized by monads (moggi cf http://mirrors.csl.sri.com/www.brics.dk/%257Ehosc/local/LaSC-7-1-pp39-56.pdf

Comment: That said, my goal is to then untie the recursion to compositionally add features in the recursion loop, (tying it back with a ycombinator) in which case expression builder would not be a nice fit.. Unless I can produce them compositionally as well..

Comment: I don't have any specific links, but Schemers often study this kind of thing so maybe you can find some good stuff here: [http://library.readscheme.org/page6.html](http://library.readscheme.org/page6.html). But basically, the CPS conversion is somewhat like compiling to low-level code, where you make the order of operations explicit, and the "stack" is explicitly managed: wrapping k in a new function = push, applying k = pop/return, passing k unchanged = tail call.

Comment: @nicolas I loved Appel's "Compiling with continuations" http://www.amazon.com/Compiling-Continuations-Andrew-W-Appel/dp/052103311X

Comment: @JonHarrop thanks, I will read that. I imagine you saw http://www.ccs.northeastern.edu/home/dbrown/papers/tr-memo-mixins.pdf and Nick's implementation's http://fssnip.net/3v . I like this idea of unrolling / injecting / rollling as inheritance.

Comment: @JonHarrop that one looks interesting as well http://okmij.org/ftp/meta-programming/#staged-monad